# Input output of a text file from a online server

Tags: java, c++, qt, input, cloud

I am developing my first chess game with Qt( C++ GUI ). For that I would like to take input from an online server. It may be just a text file.( Actually Just to take the latest FEN string ). I don't know any way how can I interact with a server. Is there any simple way to interact with a web server or cloud server or just a way to download a text file then read it using Qt.

In case of failure, I can also change my platform from Qt to JAVA( as it is just to converting the whole algorithm ) but I just need a simpler way to text file input output say just like calling a function with suitable argument to get the text file. My biggest complication is the i/o. As I have mostly done the project in Qt, so solution with the Qt will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Thanks, I already asked this time. Next time I will try to be on right style.

Answer (score 2):

In many such cases, it is best to have a look at the documentation of your framework, especially the example and help section.
For example, if you look at the [Qt Network examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-network.html), you will find a lot of snippets, which implement any kind of network connection.

For how the interaction works, this may be too broad to answer. It depends on the server you want to connect to. Normally, there is a protocol specified, which describes the communication and how you have to query your information (simple HTTP request/response, JSON, TCP, ...).

That being said, Qt is perfectly capable of interacting with a server, and there is no need to switch to another language if you don't want to.